# No such file or directory webdriver_prefs.json when compiling to exe with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, cx-freeze

I wrote an application using selenium firefox webdriver and compiled it with cx_Freeze. When I start my application I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\111\ui\__init__.py", line 27, in login
    self.browser = self.webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.profile = FirefoxProfile()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 63, in __init__
    WEBDRIVER_PREFERENCES)) as default_prefs:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\111\\build\\exe.win32-3.4\\library.zip\\selenium\\webdriver\\firefox\\webdriver_prefs.json'
```

But my library.zip actually contains webdriver_prefs.json and webdriver.xpi. I use next setup.py file to add it:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base= 'C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver'

includes = [
    ('%s\\firefox\\webdriver.xpi' %(base), 'selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.xpi'), 
    ('%s\\firefox\\webdriver_prefs.json '%(base), 'selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver_prefs.json')
]

build_exe_options = {
    "packages": ["os"], 
    "excludes": ["tkinter"],
    "zip_includes": includes,
}

setup(
    name = "lala", 
    version = "0.1", 
    description = "lalala", 
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options}, 
    executables = [Executable("app.py", base=base)],
)
```

Shoud I somehow register this files for my executable? And why traceback prints filepaths with two ways (one backslash and two backslashes)?

Comment: did you solve this problem in meanwhile?

Comment: yes, I solved it with PyInstaller, you can check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I wasn't able to solve problem with `cx_Freeze` but then I tried `PyInstaller` and it works like a charm! It supports Python3 already by the way. I used that command:

`c:\Python34\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe -p C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages -F app.py`